# Why Nuxtjs Axios Proxy is not working on server?

Tags: laravel, nginx, proxy, axios, nuxt.js

I'm struggling for few days to find a solution. It seems that my nuxt/axios proxy configuration are not taken into account when my site is on production. Locally everything is working fine but once the site is on the server my ajax calls hit `mysite.com/api/ect...` instead of being proxy to `mysite.com/api/v1/ect`. I tried to play with axios.baseURL and various configuration but nothing seems to work.

```
axios: {
    proxy: true,
    credentials: true,
},

proxy: {
    '/api/': { target: 'mysite.com/api/v1', pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''} },
},
```

Maybe the issue comes from my Nginx configuration ? I use a reverse proxy to serve a nuxt app on mysite.com and a laravel api on mysite.com/api. Can this be the problem ?

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/mysite.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mysite.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /home/forge/api/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/....
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/....

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers .....
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/mysite.com/server/*;

    location /api {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/mysite.com/after/*;
```

Thanks for your help and recommendation,

Comment: axios's config.proxy is Node.js only. it is meaningless in browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can i proceed then ? This is the NuxtJS doc about it: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#proxy. As explained locally it works perfectly. It's only when i put the site live that the url are not proxy by axios

Comment: Did you put the `env variables` on the production server?

Comment: Yes. API_URL and BASE_URL are set. But even hard coding the url in the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use API_URL if you use proxy mode. Use `prefix` instead of.
2. Turn on debug for check the proxyRequest:

proxy property in nuxt.config.js:

```
proxy: {
     
// target, others options

     logLevel: ‘debug’,

     onProxyReq(proxyReq, req, res) {

       // console.log here

     }
}
```